# How to retrieve UID from firebase and add it to child of firebase DB

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

first off I am very new to firebase database. I am looking into how do i retrieve the current UID (that is currenty logged into) from firebase and insert it into child of firebase along with a value all through the oncreate.

I'm trying to push mycurrent UID and it's value to Firebase. I am having trouble pushing it to firebase. Here is my firebase structure:

[image]
(e.g, UID `Fo2SfEfryWEjmxr4yIQwM5LQQx2`and the value `'720'`in fire base)

After trying out, i am still unable to get the following code to retrieve UID. I'm having trouble with `(new ValueEventListener()` as well as this line.

```
Map<String, Queue> data = postSnapshot.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Queue>>() {});
```

Here is my onCreate for reference

```
    mRef = new Firebase("https://sunwayfinancequeue.firebaseio.com/");
    mRef.child("UserQueue");
    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Queue queue = postSnapshot.getValue(Queue.class);
                System.out.println(Queue.getTotalqueue() + " - " + Queue.getServingqueue());
                Map<String, Queue> data = postSnapshot.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Queue>>() {});
                Map.Entry<String, Queue> entry = data.entrySet().iterator().next();
                String uid = entry.getKey();
                Log.d("Firebase UID ", uid);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

Here is my constructor:

```
public class Queue {

private static double servingqueue;
private static double totalqueue;
private static String uid;

public Queue(Double servingqueue, Double totalqueue) {
    Queue.servingqueue = servingqueue;
    Queue.totalqueue = totalqueue;

}

public static double getServingqueue() {
    return servingqueue;
}

public static void setServingqueue(double servingqueue) {
    Queue.servingqueue = servingqueue;
}

public static double getTotalqueue() {
    return totalqueue;
}

public static void setTotalqueue(double totalqueue) {
    Queue.totalqueue = totalqueue;
}

public static String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public static void setUid(String uid) {
    Queue.uid = uid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the legacy [Firebase Database SDK, 2.5.x](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/).  If you are just getting started with using the database, it would be better to use the new [9.x.x SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), especially if you are using Firebase Authentication from the new SDK.  You will likely encounter problems if you use the old and new SDKs in the same build.  See the [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

Comment: Thanks. I am using the latest `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'`

Comment: But given the code you posted, you must also have `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.x'` in your build dependencies.  That is the legacy SDK.

Comment: That would explain certain things does not work. thanks for noticing. But does the latest `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0` able to make the changes i have in store?

Comment: Yes, it should work after you add a no-arg constructor to `Queue`.  I'm not sure about your use of `static` for the two fields of Queue.  That may be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use Firebase authentication. Check out this link to set up Firebase authentication for your Android App:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

This link will help you manage the users and show you how to get the current user's UID:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Once you have Firebase Authentication set up you would use this piece of code to get the UID of the current user.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    String UID = user.getUid();
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've set up firebase auth not long ago. But I'm having issues of sending uid back to firebase db along with a value that i have in store.